# NLTK Converting Chunks to Strings

Tags: python, nltk

Right now I have chunks:

```
('together', 'RB')
(Chunk outer/JJ space/NN)
```

And i'm attempting to convert that strings:

```
"together"
"outer space"
```

On the surface this seems straight forward, but apparently they're organized in a tree of tuples? Does NLTK provide a simple way to go from a chunk to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html#module-nltk.chunk) for `nltk.chunk`:

> To convert a chunk structure back to a list of tokens, simply use the
>   chunk structure's `leaves()` method.

see the `nltk.tree.Tree.leaves()` docs [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.leaves)